# non-static variable error when creating own class

Tags: java, arrays, static, non-static

I often struggle with non-static variable errors. Not sure I have understood the purpose properly when to use static and not. I have the below code where I'm trying to parse a csv file with three columns (date, time, temperature) in to a class I have defined myself.

This bit gives me a non-static variable error.

```
    TempData objt = new TempData();
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong I'd be very grateful. I've tried google but can't find anything relevant.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.sql.Timestamp;



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date tempDate;
        Date tempTime;
        Double tempTemperature;

        ArrayList<TempData> data = new ArrayList<TempData>();
        TempData objt = new TempData();


        //Get scanner instance
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("smhi-opendata.csv"));

        //Set the delimiter used in file
        scanner.useDelimiter(";");

        //Get all tokens and store them in some data structure
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            tempDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(scanner.next());
            tempTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(scanner.next());
            tempTemperature = Double.parseDouble(scanner.next());
            objt.Data(tempDate, tempTime, tempTemperature);
           data.add(objt);
        }

        //Do not forget to close the scanner
        scanner.close();

        }


    public class TempData{
        private Date date;
        private Date time;
        private double temperature;

        public void Data (Date d, Date t, double te){
            date = d;
            time = t;
            temperature = te;

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: @Lino what are you talking about? he's calling the default constructor. Your suggestion would just screw up a method (that should have been called data). Removing the void keyword 'll just make sure his constructor calls are no longer working, and an error message about 'wrong type', since public Data is not a valid constructor for the TempData class

Comment: @Lino is right by telling you to make `TempData` a `static class`. The method that looks a little like a constructor is more like a *bundle of setters*. You should add a `try`-`catch` around the code that uses a `Scanner` and `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

First off the Data function just updates the values rather than create a new TempData object. Secondly the main function can't use the TempData class where it is currently.

I'd go for something like this instead:

```
public class TempData {
    private Date date;
    private Date time;
    private double temperature;

    public TempData(Date date, Date time, double temperature) {
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Date tempDate;
        Date tempTime;
        Double tempTemperature;

        ArrayList<TempData> data = new ArrayList<TempData>();

        // Get scanner instance
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("smhi-opendata.csv"));

        // Set the delimiter used in file
        scanner.useDelimiter(";");

        // Get all tokens and store them in some data structure
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            tempDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(scanner.next());
            tempTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(scanner.next());
            tempTemperature = Double.parseDouble(scanner.next());
            TempData objt = new TempData(tempDate, tempTime, tempTemperature);
            data.add(objt);
        }

        // Do not forget to close the scanner
        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are accessing a non static class from a static context. The `main` method (`public static void main() {}`) has the keyword `static` so it is in the class (static) context. Your inner class `TempData` is not static, so it belongs to the instance (non static) context.

**You can access the class context from instance context, but not vice versa.** So you have tow options:

Move your `TempData` class to the static context:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        TempData objt = new TempData();
        // ...
    }

    public static class TempData{
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or access your `TempData` from non static context. For example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        // ...
        TempData objt = new TempData();
        // ...
    }

    public class TempData {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To read more about this you can follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) official explanation.